# Filter in Graphical Query parser Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a structure where I want to search my documents and filter/rank/set conditions on my parents. Example, a doc is a match because it contains my searched string, but also because its parent contains a certain value.

Using the graph parser and experimenting with the filter is the best way I have noticed doing this. I tried block join child parser first but it wouldn't do it for me.

The problem I am facing now is that I can't seem to get the filter to work in this way:
`traversalFilter="(-field:x) OR (field2:y)"`

Meaning, if `field` does not have value `x` it is ok, if `field` has value `x` and `field2` has `y` its also ok. Other cases is filtered away.

But it won't work. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit** for more information:
I have set up a test core with all my fields stored in a text_general field. Default `solrconfig`. I have a simple chaining I'm using from parameter as `document id`. And a to field storing all ids of each documents children. And the graph parser works fine, its just this kind of filter that does not work for me.

I have documents with field with value a or b.

A query like this:

```
q=*
fq={!graph from=id to=to returnRoot=false traversalFilter="(field:b)" }id:0
```

This query filters away any document and its children that do not have b as value on field.

```
q=*
fq={!graph from=id to=to returnRoot=false traversalFilter="(-field:b)" }id:0
```

Should then work in the opposite. Filter away documents with b as value. But this does not work for some reason.

**Edit:**
from solrquerysyntax:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Pure negative queries (all clauses prohibited) are allowed.- `inStock:false` finds all field values where `inStock` is not false

Which is why `q=* fq=-(field:x)` works fine, in returning all documents not containing value x in field.

So why can't I add the same filter in the graph traversal

**EDIT3:**
I have now started looking on the graph parser and have noticed that when filtering `-(-field:x)` is the same as `+field:x`. But `+(-field:x)` is not the same as `-field:x` and does not work.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of schema.xml and solrconfig.xml. Show your query and any incorrect results.